# Run jUnit and spock tests together via Maven

Tags: maven, unit-testing, junit, spock

I'm trying to cover my SpringBoot application with unit tests. Application is written in Kotlin. Since now, I had two unit test using Kotlin and jUnit and one integration test using Spock. Using Maven, I'm able to execute them properly. I've tried to add another unit test using groovy/spock. When I run this test from file, it works properly. But when I run maven, this test is ignored and I don't know why. I already spend few hours trying to find solution, but without luck.

Here is test folder structure:

```
├───groovy
│   │
│   └───integration
│       │   ITTestSuite.groovy
│       │
│       ├───pages
│       │       ZMainPage.groovy
│       │
│       └───test
│               ZMainSpec.groovy
│
├───kotlin
│   └───com
│       └───example
│           └───zou
│               │   ZouApplicationTests.kt
│               │
│               ├───model
│               │       ArticleTest.kt -- jUnit
│               │       PortalTest.kt -- jUnit
│               │
│               └───services
│                       TextAnalysisServiceSpec.groovy -- Spock
│                       TextAnalysisServiceTest.kt -- jUnit
```

Maven build phase:

```
    <build>
    <sourceDirectory>${project.basedir}/src/main/kotlin</sourceDirectory>
    <testSourceDirectory>${project.basedir}/src/test/kotlin</testSourceDirectory>
    <plugins>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.codehaus.gmavenplus</groupId>
            <artifactId>gmavenplus-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>1.6</version>
            <executions>
                <execution>
                    <goals>
                        <goal>generateStubs</goal>
                        <goal>compile</goal>
                        <goal>generateTestStubs</goal>
                        <goal>compileTests</goal>
                    </goals>
                </execution>
            </executions>
            <dependencies>
                <dependency>
                    <groupId>org.codehaus.groovy</groupId>
                    <artifactId>groovy-all</artifactId>
                    <version>${groovy.version}</version>
                </dependency>
            </dependencies>
        </plugin>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            <configuration>
                <wait>1000</wait>
                <maxAttempts>180</maxAttempts>
            </configuration>
            <executions>
                <execution>
                    <id>run-integration-tests</id>
                    <goals>
                        <goal>start</goal>
                    </goals>
                    <configuration>
                        <skip>${skipITs}</skip>
                    </configuration>
                </execution>
                <execution>
                    <id>post-integration-test</id>
                    <goals>
                        <goal>stop</goal>
                    </goals>
                    <configuration>
                        <skip>${skipITs}</skip>
                    </configuration>
                </execution>
            </executions>
        </plugin>
        <plugin>
            <artifactId>kotlin-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            <groupId>org.jetbrains.kotlin</groupId>
            <version>${kotlin.version}</version>
            <configuration>
                <compilerPlugins>
                    <plugin>spring</plugin>
                </compilerPlugins>
                <jvmTarget>1.8</jvmTarget>
            </configuration>
            <executions>
                <execution>
                    <id>compile</id>
                    <phase>compile</phase>
                    <goals>
                        <goal>compile</goal>
                    </goals>
                </execution>
                <execution>
                    <id>test-compile</id>
                    <phase>test-compile</phase>
                    <goals>
                        <goal>test-compile</goal>
                    </goals>
                </execution>
            </executions>
            <dependencies>
                <dependency>
                    <groupId>org.jetbrains.kotlin</groupId>
                    <artifactId>kotlin-maven-allopen</artifactId>
                    <version>${kotlin.version}</version>
                </dependency>
            </dependencies>
        </plugin>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
            <artifactId>maven-surefire-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>2.20.1</version>
            <configuration>
                <skipTests>${skipUTs}</skipTests>
                <includes>
                    <include>**/*Spec.java</include>
                    <include>**/*Test.*</include>
                </includes>
            </configuration>
        </plugin>
```

The problem is, whenever I run

```
mvn test

mvn verify
```

only jUnit test both with integration test are started. The `TextAnalysisServiceSpec.groovy` is never executed.

Here is part of Maven output:

```
[INFO] --- gmavenplus-plugin:1.6:compile (default) @ zou ---
[INFO] Using Groovy 2.4.13 to perform compile.
[INFO] No sources specified for compilation.  Skipping.
```

I found few questions here on StackOverflow which asked almost the same or similar question, but none of response worked in my project.

What I've already tried:

1. Adding configuration with  to gmavenplus-plugin
2. **/*Spec.java this with extension .groovy (few answers says that .java do the trick since surefire wont work for groovy)
3. Moving file TextAnalysisServiceSpec.groovy under groovy/ folder

None of them work for me. The `TextAnalysisServiceTest.kt` contains the same test written using Kotlin, which is compiled and run during execution. But I still want to be able to write and run Spock test.

**EDIT**:
It seems the problem is that this:

```
    <execution>
        <id>test-compile</id>
        <phase>test-compile</phase>
        <goals>
            <goal>test-compile</goal>
        </goals>
    </execution>
```

overwrites compiled groovy spock test. Because if I comment this part of configuration, test is under compiled classes and runs during mvn test. What to do with that?

Comment: `TextAnalysisServiceSpec.groovy` is in the Kotlin folder.

Comment: You should add this as an actual answer instead of in your question.  I'll check back in a few hours to see if you've done that; if not, I'll add it in as an answer for you.

Comment: @Makoto, Thank you for notice. I already did that. :-)

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57165511/spock-test-together-with-junit-5-test-does-not-run

Answer (score 0):

The solution is explained here - https://kotlinlang.org/docs/reference/using-maven.html under Compiling Kotlin and Java source:

> To compile mixed code applications Kotlin compiler should be invoked before Java compiler

The word **mixed** is important since this also fits this case with groovy. :-)