# Application context is reloaded for every Spock specification when using EmbeddedKafka

Tags: spring-boot, spock, spring-boot-test, embedded-kafka

I have a spring boot application with integration test setup. I have a base groovy class which I extend in every specification. Spring boot version 2.0.6
My problem is that application context is restarted for each specification.

I will appreciate any help with this.
Thanks.

People seem to have this issue when they use either DirtiesContext or MockBean. I dont have either.

This is what the base looks like

```java
@SpringBootTest(classes = [Application],
                webEnvironment = SpringBootTest.WebEnvironment.RANDOM_PORT)
@ActiveProfiles("spring-boot-test")
class SpringBootTestBase extends Specification {
...
}
```

I expect all my tests to use the same context.

Comment: Thanks for your code snippet, but that is not particularly helpful. Please provide an [MCVE](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve), something I can build and run in order to reproduce your problem. I just easily [answered another question](https://stackoverflow.com/a/57174570/1082681) (unrelated to yours, just an example) where an answer was impossible without an MCVE. After I had it, no problem. So preparing the MCVE helps you to get the help you need.

Comment: Hi. Thanks for your reply. I actually just figured whats wrong. I am using EmbeddedKafka and it is recreated with every spec hence reloading the context

Comment: Okay, I added an _embedded-kafka_ tag to your question and updated the headline/subject.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem was EmbeddedKafka. It is recreated and reloads the context.
Using this https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-kafka/blob/master/src/reference/asciidoc/testing.adoc#using-the-same-brokers-for-multiple-test-classes fixes the issue.